# Most efficient way to loop in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 SQL Server tables:

```
Players (
    PlayerID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Money INT
)
Game (
    GameID INT,
    PlayerID INT
)
```

I need to make a query that lists the player with the most money for each games. What would be the best way to do this?

I assume it should be something with this logic:

```
foreach(games)
{
   playersInGame = GetPlayersInGame()   
   return playerWithMostMoney from playersInGame
}
```

But I'm pretty bad in TSQL.

Comment: learn basic sql, especially joins, then it's just a matter of an appropriate `order by` clause.

Comment: You _almost never_ need to loop in SQL. `GROUP BY` aggregates and joins are typically the correct approach instead.

Comment: To learn basic sql, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way. To format text as a code block (with syntax highlighting), highlight your text and click the `{}` button in the toolbar or `ctl-k`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Michael, I'll look into the GROUP BY approach!

Comment: "Loop through" = RBAR.  RBAR != Set Based.  RBAR Bad, RBAR die now.

Comment: That data design is odd to me.  A player shares money across games?  What game is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using SQL, you want to use the `join` and `group by` operations to do work that would be done using loops in other languages.  SQL has a lot of advantages over such languages, particularly because the optimizer can choose from a variety of ways of implementing the logic.  SQL engines can take advantage of multiple processors, for instance, which is difficult in procedural languages.

In your case, the logic has two parts.  The first is to join the tables together, which gives you the amount of money for all players.  The second is to find the best one.  For this, I'm going to use the window function `max()` to get the maximum money amount (I would often use `row_number()` for th is, but I think `max()` is easier to explain):

```
select g.gameid, p.playerid, p.money
from (select g.gameid, p.playerid, p.money,
             max(p.money) over (partition by g.gameid) as MaxMoneyPerGame
      from games g join
           players p
           on g.playerid = p.playerid
     ) gp
where gp.money = gp.maxmoney;
```

The expression `max(p.money) over (partition by g.gameid)` is calculating the maximum of money for each game (based on the `partition by` clause).  The final `where` clause is choosing the player whose money matches the maximum.

Note that if two players have the same maximum, they will both be chosen.  `row_number()` is an alternative that would always choose only one player, even when there are duplicates with the same maximum money value.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could use `over` with `max`.  I've only used it with `row_number` and `rank`.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Gordon's answer, but using `rank`:

```
select gameid, playerid, money
from (select g.gameid, p.playerid, p.money,
             rank() over (partition by g.gameid order by p.money desc) rn
      from games g 
      join players p on g.playerid = p.playerid
     ) sq
where rn=1
```